# Como retornar um uma resposta do sql?

Tags: java, sql, query

Essa é minha primeira publicação num forum, então peço desculpas se cometer algum erro.

É o seguinte, preciso cadastrar um livro no banco, mas antes disso, precisaria saber se o autor já está cadastrado no banco, pois se nao tiver, devo cadastrar primeiro. 
Então pensei em criar um metodo "verificaAutor" que consultaria a tabela Autor no banco, e caso nao houvesse o nome digitado pelo usuario, direcionaria para a tela de cadastro.
Pensei em dar um select no banco, e caso nao encontrasse nada, retornasse null,
tipo um

```
if (RESULTADODOBANCO = null)
         cadastroAutor.setVisible(true);
```

Porem nao faço ideia de como fazer isso, fiz um

```
String sql="SELECT nome FROM autor WHERE nome=?";
    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setString   (5, livro.getAutor());
```

no meu metodo verificaAutor, mas nao sei como saber se retornou null

PERDOEM-ME SE ESTIVER MUITO CONFUSO

Comment: Acho que uma abordagem para pular essa etapa de verificar se o autor que o cara digitou existe, seria, ao invés dele digitar o nome do autor na hora de cadastrar o livro, você criar um `select` com todos os autores do Banco de Dados, e o usuário selecionar qual ele quer.

Comment: Rick, obrigado pela resposta rápida. Esse trabalho tá me surtando! kk
No caso, o cliente iria estar na tela de cadastro do livro, digitaria o nome do autor, e na hora que clicasse no botao CADASTRAR, chamaria o metodo verificaAutor(), esse método verificaria no banco se o autor está cadastro, se nao, encaminharia o usuario para a tela de cadastro

Comment: No caso vc quis dizer que tivesse tipo uma tabela com o nome de todos os autores cadastrados, e caso nao encontrasse, o usuario clicasse no botao pra cadastrar o autor, isso?

Desculpe pela complicacão, sou novo em programação

Comment: Muito Bem Weslley, só dei uma sugestão de uma outra abordagem, mas já vou responder sua dúvida.

Comment: A abordagem que sugerir, é que na tela de cadastro do livro, tenha um campo do tipo `select` onde será listado todos os autores e o usuário irá escolher qual ele quer, assim não existe a possibilidade dele escolher um autor que não existe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muito simples amigo. Tendo o seu `ResultSet` em mãos, bastá você fazer um simples `if` no méteodo `next()` dele.
Exemplo:

```
if (rs.next()) {
    // Autor encontrado
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Autor não encontrado");
    // Redirecionar para o cadastro
}
```

Comment: O metodo next() retorna true ou false? 

Ou seja, se retornar false, significa que nao encontrou nenhum registro?

Comment: Sim Weslley. Se a minha resposta te ajudou, de um certo nela, isso vai me ajudar bastante